# Database binding for OCaml?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, ocaml

I'm trying to find a library to access a database from an OCaml program. After trying [ocaml-sqlite](http://neugierig.org/software/ocaml/sqlite/), I'm not satisfied, since it's somewhat slow.

I've seen a MySQL module, but it doesn't seem to be maintained.

Comment: you can always write your own C interfaces for the db/functionality you need... but I've used ocaml-mysql for a small project (used only simple, insert/update/select queries, though).

Comment: but does ocaml-mysql work with recent mysql releases ? Should I rather use postgres ?
That's rather basic DB stuff..

Comment: I use mysql-ocaml with a mysql v5 remote db. Although, my specific operations are not v5 specific though, as mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked the [Caml Hump](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=24)?  It has links to plenty of database bindings.

Good, mature, bindings that I can recommend are PG'OCaml by Richard Jones and postgresql-ocaml by Markus Mottl.  They are both targeted at Postgresql (which is a probably a better choice for you considering you're into Ocaml).

Comment: sure, i've checked this...my concern was that the last releases seem quite old. So i wanted to know what people were actually using.

Comment: What do you mean by quite old?  In the case of PG'OCaml the latest release is a few months old and there seems to be constant activity in SVN.  As for postgresql-ocaml, there are no new release because there's no need to upgrade what runs fine... :-)

Comment: ok, my bad, I didn't go to the PG'Ocaml new web site. and for postgresql-ocaml, I didn't want to invest time on something I cannot use. thx.

Comment: I'll give it a try. By modifying my schemas, the parsing/insertion in sqlite is much faster, but postgresql seems attractive.

Answer (score 3):

ocaml-mysql works without problems here - mysql api for connect/query/fetch doesn't change that much :)
It lacks prepared statements though, had to implement mysql_stmt_* wrappers myself.

Comment: I use the MySQL bindings fairly heavily, including the prepared statement support. They work well with 5.0.x and 5.5.x in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite surprised that you find the ocaml-sqlite bindings slow.  sqlite is fast on its own, and I believe the sqlite bindings are very well written.  You should make sure you're using the up-to-date binding from [Markus Mottl's page](http://www.ocaml.info/home/ocaml_sources.html)

Comment: maybe i'm a bit demanding, I'm parsing a 100 Mo text file and building a the database. I've many inserts to do, so I had to be more clever concerning the calls to exec. I'm using the last version. I don't know what is the performance penalty induced by the IO to the data base. file

Comment: Only 100Mo?! I parse that in my sleep... literally!

Comment: i don't know what to answer :-). You're parsing it in your sleep because it takes so long that you fall asleep ?

Comment: Consider using prepared statements to reduce overhead of multiple INSERT's.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), I recommend [ocaml-postgresql](https://bitbucket.org/mmottl/postgresql-ocaml). (There is also [ocaml-sql](https://github.com/perf101/ocaml-sql), which makes some SQL operations more convenient when using ocaml-postgresql.)

Since [PG'OCaml](http://pgocaml.forge.ocamlcore.org/) heavily relies on the OCaml's compile-time type system, it is impossible to compose queries at runtime, which makes it, in my opinion, not useful in most real-world scenarios.